# How can I remove the gap on top of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The gap is somehow conected to the back function. If I pull down the navigation bar the app returns to the last view, but I don't want the option to go back a view.

I don't know where to search for it.

[image: Screenshot]

if the picture doesn't work. Here is the Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tse4oehn6o47bw/IMG_9159.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `UIViewController`'s `modalPresentationStyle` property to `.fullScreen`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle

Comment: `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

like this?

Comment: Yes, or you can set it in IB.

Comment: Some code or IB screenshots might help. Just so I’m clear, this is a modal view controller that slides up from the bottom, yes?

Comment: [Screenshot Storyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9aki4kna03z90l6/Bildschirmfoto%202019-09-04%20um%2019.53.04.png?dl=0)

 This is my Storyboard. There is not much to see in the code. When I open the second view, it slides over the first one

Comment: Click on your navigation controller (the middle one). In the attributes inspector, find "Presentation" and change it to "Full Screen".